# String a Date conservando formato (Java)

Tags: java, date

Talvez la pregunta sea muy básica pero me gustaría saber como pasar un String a Date conservando el formato, tengo el siguiente codigo:

1.- Creo un objeto Date:

```
Date date=new Date();
//date= Fri Aug 14 21:02:51 CDT 2020
```

2.- Defino el formato que quiero obtener:

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

3.- Guardo en un String la fecha del paso 1 con el formato que quiero obtener (paso 2).

```
String fechaActual = sdf.format(date);
/**Hasta aquí todo va bien y tendría lo siguiente:
fechaActual= 2020-08-14T21:02:51    
*/
```

4.-El problema es cuando asigno el valor de "fechaActual" (String) a "miFecha" (de tipo Date), vuelve a tomar el formato inicial del paso 1.

```
Date miFecha=sdf.parse(fechaActual);
//miFecha= Fri Aug 14 21:02:51 CDT 2020
```

Quisiera ver si hay alguna forma pasar un String a Date conservando el formato del paso 2. Gracias

Comment: Lo unico que podrias hacer es crear una clase ejemplo MyDate y extender de Date y sobrescribir el metodo toString para que ahi hagas el formato de fecha y desde el mismo objeto ya tengas el formateo. Tambien puedas agregar metodos personalizados.

Answer (score 3):

Un *`java.util.Date`* no tiene "formato"; solo representa un instante de tiempo<sup>1</sup>.

El "formato" que tú ves es el resultado de convertir el *Date* de nuevo a *`String`* usando el método *`java.util.Date#toString()`*, que genera una descripción humana de la fecha representada por el *`Date`*. No es algo que se guarde en el objeto. El formato proporcionado por este método [está definido en el Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString()) y es fijo.

La solución es usar *`SimpleDateFormat#format`* cada vez que quieras convertir el *Date* a una fecha con un formato determinado.

---

<sup>1</sup>Normalmente lo hace guardando un `long` que representa los milisegundos desde el 1/1/1970. Pero en realidad podría usar cualquier otra solución.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso creo que para simplificar las tareas podrias crear una clase que extiendas de Date y sobrescribas algunos metodos y agregar otros. Aclarar tambien que la clase Date la mayoria de sus propiedades/metodos estan obsoletas y se recomienda usar Calendar.

Clase que extiende Date:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class MyDate extends Date {
    
    private String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
    private Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    private TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    
    public MyDate(long date) {
        super(date);
    }
    
    public MyDate(int year,
            int month,
            int date,
            int hrs,
            int min,
            int sec) {
        super(year, month, date, hrs, min, sec);
    }
    
    public MyDate(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min) {
        super(year, month, date, hrs, min);
    }
    
    public MyDate() {
        super();
    }
    
    public MyDate(String dateString) throws ParseException {
        super();
        this.setDate(dateString);
    }
    
    public MyDate(int year, int month, int date) {
        super(year, month, date);
    }
    
    public MyDate(Date date) {
        super(date.getTime());
    }
    
    public void setTimeZone(TimeZone tz) {
        this.tz = tz;
    }
    
    public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }
    
    public void setFormat(String format) {
        this.format = format;
    }
    
    public void setDate(String date) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        Date d = formatter.parse(date);
        super.setTime(d.getTime());
    }
    
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        super.setTime(date.getTime());
    }
    
    public void setDate(MyDate date) {
        super.setTime(date.getTime());
    }
    
    public Date getMyDate() {
        return new Date(super.getTime());
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter;
        if (this.locale != null) {
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format, this.locale);
        } else {
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        }
        if (this.tz != null) {
            formatter.setTimeZone(tz);
        }
        
        String result = formatter.format(super.getTime());
        return result;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Ejemplo de Uso:

```
try {
        MyDate date1 = new MyDate();
        System.out.println(date1);
        MyDate date2 = new MyDate(date1.toString());
        System.out.println(date2);
        MyDate date3 = new MyDate("2020-08-14T21:02:51");
        System.out.println(date3);
        MyDate date4 = new MyDate(date3);
        System.out.println(date4);
        MyDate date5 = new MyDate(new Date());
        System.out.println(date5);
        date1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(date1);
        date1.setFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(date1);

        /*SALIDA:
        2020-08-15T12:31:44
        2020-08-15T12:31:44
        2020-08-14T21:02:51
        2020-08-14T21:02:51
        2020-08-15T12:31:45
        2020-08-15T11:31:44
        15/08/2020 11:31:44*/
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: El problema con eso es que el Javadoc de *java.util.Date* especifica el formato. Así con esto estás creando una subclase que cambia el comportamiento (contrato) de la superclase, lo cual es un mal diseño (busca información sobre el *principio de substitución*). Por no hablar que se debería favorecer composición sobre herencia; crear una subclase cuando puedes crear un formateador (o usar los que ya existen) no es buena idea.

Comment: Hasta donde veo del código no cambia ningun comportamiento, A excepción de sobreescribir el metodo ToString y agregar algunas funciones que no afectan la superclase.

Comment: *A excepción de sobreescribir el metodo ToString.* Precisamente. Ve a la documentación del método y te especifica el formato. Si lo cambias, estás creando un *java.util.Date* (porque las instancias de tu nueva clase también son instancias de las superclases) que no cumple la especificación de *Date*, Un código que espere que *toString* devuelva ese formato tendrá problemas si le pasas una instancia de tu clase. Repasa lo que es el principio de sustitución, y porqué es importante cumplirlo.

Comment: Seria importante que muestres un link del problema que pueda presentar el sobrescribir toString. Me he leido la documentación de oracle acerca de ese metodo y nada afecta al menos que quieras intanciar otro dateTime usando el toString de la clase que hereda. En ese caso el usuario es conciente de eso y generaria un problema en tiempo de ejecución nada inesperado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta